# Send an Audio File in a multipart/form-data Form POST Using Remix.run (1.16)

Tags: next.js, next-auth, remix.run

I'm trying to send an audio file to the server side through a post request of a form.

I'm trying to use unstable_parseMultipartFormData in conbination with multipart/form-data Form as instructed on Remix documentation [here](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/utils/parse-multipart-form-data) but I get this **error: TypeError: uploadHandler2 is not a function
at parseMultipartFormData**

Im trying to use this file on server side inside the action.

```
export const action = async ({ request, context }) => {
   const formData = await unstable_parseMultipartFormData(
      request,
      uploadHandler
   );
   return ''
};

export default function Index() {
   const submit = useSubmit()
   const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
      audioFile: '',
   });

   const handleFileChange = (event) => {
      setFormData({ audioFile: event.target.files[0] });
   };

   const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      submit(formData, { method: "post" });
   };

   return (
      <>
         <section>
            <Form encType="multipart/form-data" method="POST" >
               <input
                  id="fileUpload"
                  name="audioFile"
                  type="file"
                  accept=".mp3,.m4a"
                  // onChange={handleFileChange}
                  className="bg-neutral-600 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-lg mb-4 w-full text-sm"
               />
               <button className="text-white border border-white p-2 rounded-md text-sm" type="submit">Send</button>
            </Form>

         </section>
      </>
   );
}
```

Help is be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload files, you need to set the `<Form encType>`:

```js
<Form method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="audioFile" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</Form>
```

Then create an action with an uploadHandler:

```js
import { 
  unstable_createMemoryUploadHandler,
  unstable_parseMultipartFormData, 
} from '@remix-run/node';

export const action = async ({ request }: ActionArgs) => {
  const uploadHandler = unstable_createMemoryUploadHandler({
    maxPartSize: 500_000,
  });
  const formData = await unstable_parseMultipartFormData(
    request,
    uploadHandler
  );
  // now you can get the audio file as a File object
  const audioFile = formData.get("audioFile") as File;
  ...
}
```

https://remix.run/docs/en/1.16.1/utils/parse-multipart-form-data